# WPBakery Page Builder with taxonomy dropdown not working

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to build a custom element for WPBakery Page Builder with a dropdown where custom taxonomy elements (categories) are listed.

Unfortunately I end up with empty dropdown elements. What am I doing wrong here?

The $options array gets filled perfectly when I var_dump it.

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy'    => 'team',
    'hide_empty'  => false,
));

$options = array();

foreach($terms as $team) {
  $options[$team->name] = $team->slug;
}
```

This is my params array inside the **vc_map()** function:

```
'params'        => array(
      array(
        'type'          => 'dropdown',
        'holder'        => 'div',
        'class'         => '',
        'heading'       => 'Team',
        'param_name'    => 'category',
        'value'         => $options
      )
    )
```

Comment: you have to debug to print_r($options) and then check any blank value present in array.

Comment: I used print_r but there's no blank value as expected. When trying to add the vc element in the editor I get an javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of null".

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem today.

After four hours fiddling around and trying everything, we finally found out that we were using a reserved word as our `param_name`, it was `post_category`, which by the way, is not on the [Codex's Reserved Terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms) page, even though it definitely was one of them.

`label` also isn't on the list, but given that the error and behaviour was exactly the same, I'd advice trying to switch it for something else.